# crontab MAILFROM with name

Tags: cron, mailto

my crontab is set bellow:

```
MAILFROM=name <from@test.com>
MAILTO=to@test.com
* * * * * root echo "Message here"
```

so I get the error:

```
May  4 14:31:01 ubuntu22 CRON[71554]: (root) UNSAFE MAIL (name <from@test.com>)
```

the message is sent with default From: `Cron Daemon <root@ubuntu22>`

if I set `MAILFROM=from@test.com` it works fine but have no name.

Is there a way to custom MAILFROM with mail name and not email only?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing quotes around the MAILFROM value.
If it has a space in the value, it needs the quotes.

```
MAILFROM="name <from@test.com>"
```

Not tested.

Comment: As can be seen from the error message @cberni posted, quoting is not the problem. In fact, even `MAILFROM="<addr>"` causes the error "UNSAFE MAIL".

Comment: `man 5 crontab` claims that quoting is optional, even with spaces in your value

Answer (score 0):

By writing a shell script instead of sendmail, and judging and modifying the received email content, and forwarding the parameters to the original bsendmail to intercept and modify it.

```
mv /usr/sbin/sendmail /usr/sbin/bsendmail ; vim /usr/sbin/sendmail
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash
#/usr/sbin/sendmail

text=$(cat)
echo $text|grep -q 'Cron Daemon'&&(
  echo -e "$text"|sed '1c From: Service Notification <17351676@qq.com>' |sed '3c Subject: Scheduled Task Log' | /usr/sbin/bsendmail $*) || (
  echo -e "$text"| /usr/sbin/bsendmail $*)
exit 0;
```

---

```
chmod 777 /usr/sbin/sendmail
```